# Default login popup for web sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, popup

I am trying to build a web site with ASP.NET MVC, I'm new to this. My question is: how can I display the default login dialog? I am not referring to a custom dialog, like the jQuery Dialog, there is a default pop-up for credentials, which looks different depending on browser, same as with javascript alert(), but I don't know how to display it. To know what I mean, go to http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?WelcomeVisitors, there is a Login button at the bottom of the page, when you click it a pop-up appears. That is what I want to display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So there is no way I can do this with FormsAuthentication?

Comment: And welcome to SO. Be sure to accept answers when they are correct, even if they don't solve your problem and you will do fine here.

Comment: click on the Check Mark icon next to the question. But you need to log in as the John Quest that issued the question, it appears you have multiple logins.

Comment: Yes, well the first time I didn't have an account, I just used the email address and name. Can I still do it?

Answer (score 0):

That dialog is the result of a [challenge-response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) initiated by the server.

In the context of IIS, you would get this if you used windows authentication with no anonymous access.

You do not display this dialog or have anything to do with it other than restricting access to the resource in question.